# Using Resharper annotations can I link two properties to indicate 'not null'

Tags: c#, resharper

I have an ExchangeRate class with a nullable decimal Rate property and a boolean HasRate property that tells me whether the former is fully populated:

```
public decimal? Rate { get; private set; }
public bool HasRate => ExchangeRateMatchType != ExchangeRateMatchType.None && Rate.HasValue && Rate != 0;
```

Calling code looks like this:

```
if (referenceRate.HasRate)
{
    // ReSharper disable once PossibleInvalidOperationException
    var x = referenceRate.Rate.Value;
}
```

Given that I know that the Rate has a value when HasRate = true, is there any way to use code annotations to link those two properties so that I can get rid of the comment that disables the warning?

Comment: Contract annotations can do a lot, but only in the context of the method they're on, I'm pretty sure. Think R# must have its understanding of what `Nullable<T>.HasValue` does baked in.

Comment: Possibly, but 'baked in' in the sense that theR# team annotated the CLR. If you can annotate "nullable.HasValue means Value is not null", there should be a way to do "myClass.HasRate then Rate is okay". I need to investigate the strings that you can add to the attribute. Thanks

Comment: CLR annotations are one thing, but `HasValue` is a part of the *language* so I wouldn't expect there to be a visible annotation for that. There could well be one of course, R# is often more helpful than I expect.

Comment: Just looked at the R# external annotations files and they only have Pure for System.Nullable, so you may be right. But I still don't understand how it knows that nullable.HasValue makes Value safe to use unless, as you say, they hard coded it in their analyser.